# how to read and get specific content from a text file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

i have text file as testfile.txt content as below:

```
abc.com

test/test1/testdata.gif

xyz.com 

test2/test3/xyzdata.gif
```

i want to read this mentioned file and save with below in new file as  giftextfile.txt and content should be

```
testdata.gif

xyzdata.gif
```

i have tried below code:

```
  using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
          for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
          sr.ReadLine().Where(x=>x.Equals(".gif")).SkipWhile                    (y=>y!='/');
```

can anyone help please?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain your requirements? Currently you have almost no code, no explanation, no requirement, no rules, no logic. Just mentioning that you want _specific_ text without explaining what _specifc_ means is not enough.

Comment: Are you trying to extract only the lines that have gif extension and that too only the name?

Comment: @Bharat yes i want a name after "/" in new file

Comment: `var filenames = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(line => line.EndsWith(".gif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(Path.GetFileName)`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I wrote it with typical read and write but you just surprised me with one line. Amazing.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a text-file that contains Urls and images and you want the name of the images?

```
using System.IO;
// ...

var images = File.ReadLines(fileName)
    .Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f).Equals(".gif", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) // for example
    .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, images);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Simplest Approach**

1. Read the input file, line by line
2. Check if the line contains .gif
3. Write only the file name to new file

Code

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName);
FileInfo outputFileInfo = new FileInfo("output.txt");
StreamWriter output = outputFileInfo.CreateText();
string line = null;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.IndexOf(".gif", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
    {
        output.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(line));
    }
}
reader.Close();
output.Close();
```

**Optimized Solution, Inspired from  @Matthew Watson comment**

It does the same thing only difference is using lambda expression in LINQ's

1. File.ReadLines read all lines and reruns enumerable string
2. Here we can directly use the where filter which lambda expression to pick only those items that end with .gif
3. Finally, use the Path.GetFileName(string) to extract only name
4. We can then use File.WriteAllLines in one shot the final output

Optimized Code

```
var filenames = File.ReadLines(fileName)
            .Where(line => line.EndsWith(".gif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(Path.GetFileName);
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", filenames);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: @wyck, I didn't understood your question. It's pretty straightforward, if you think it's the same solution and copy pasted, no it's not, in fact by the time I post it other solution was posted.

Comment: Your answer is very short and does not offer any explanation and is being flagged because of its short length.  A good answer will offer some kind of text explanation, even for short solutions.  Your answer would be better if you explained, in words, (at least briefly) why it works, or what you think was the missing piece of the puzzle that the asker didn't know.  Especially since your answer is not altogether different from Tim's.

Comment: Hope the update gives some clarity. However, I saw the Tim Schmelter post after I posted mine. If you see my comment on the question, have asked for the cearification.